# NUnitRetry.SpecflowPlugin doesnt work with Selenium Errors with NUnit and Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, specflow, retry-logic

I have a Specflow and NUnit automation project using Selenium in c#. My issue is that we are using ***NUnitRetry.SpecflowPlugin*** for retries. This works fine if the test fails on an NUnit Assertion, but retries dont happen where the test fails on a Selenium or other exception. I'm just wondering has anyone encountered this and have a possible solution?

Some examples below;

**Example 1 - This is the issue**

```
[When(@"I navigate to url '(.*)'")]
public void WhenINavigateToUrl(string url)
 {
    DynamicWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
 }
```

**Example 2 - Works fine**

```
[Then(@"Web browser must be navigated to exact url '(.*)'")]
public void ThenWebBrowserMustBeNavigatedToUrl(string url)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(url, DynamicWebDriver.Url, true, $"Browser didnt navigate to url '{url}'.", $"Browser navigated to url '{url}'.");
}
```

The first example `[When(@"I navigate to url '(.*)'")]` will throw an error `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` if the website is not up but as NUnit Assertions will never be hit it doesn't perform a retry. This is the issue.

The second example `[Then(@"Web browser must be navigated to url '(.*)'")]` will throw an NUnit Assertion error if the two urls in the assertion dont match so this works fine.

I'm wondering has anyone had these issues using and come up with a solution?. Thanks in advance.